# How do I use filter EVM log events by an indexed field in web3j?

Tags: solidity, events, evm, web3j

I've looked through the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be this scenario listed. What I want to do is filter the Ethereum event log of a specific contract by an indexed field with Web3j.

Example solidity code: `event someEvent(bytes32 indexed id, bytes value);`

While we can get all the events within a specific time period using `EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(startBlock, endBlock, contractAddress);`, and filter for a specific event type by using the `Event` class, how do I get all events of a specific type that match an indexed field (for example, where `id == {0, 0, 0 ... 0}`)?

Comment: Hi @id0, I have the same question. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs https://docs.web3j.io/filters.html:

[image]

Where topics are indexed parameters of a contract event. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, found that already; there doesn't seem to be much documentation on how to use the functions `.addSingleTopic` and `.addOptionalTopics`. I know you can encode an Event object to filter for a specific event, but need to know how to compile an indexed property filter.

Comment: The `addSingleTopic` function only allows input of the type "String". I believe it must be encoded by an encoder of some type (as I've seen in the examples) I just don't know which, or what (object(s)) to encode.

Answer (score 0):

you just listen for the topic named to be a value you're interested in.

For example, I'm listening for a integer uint16 tokenId
event Emitted(uint16 indexed tokenId, address owner, uint32 timestamp);

using this code

```
String topic = String.format("0x%064X", tokenId);

EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, 
DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, ADDRESS).addSingleTopic(topic);
```